# Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'char[]' & 'char []' to 'char'

Tags: .net

```
using System;
namespace Rextester
{                   
    public class Program

{
          public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            char []My_arr = new char [5] {'1','2','3','4','5'};

            char []Arr=new char [5] {'a','b','c','d','e'};

            char []combine=new char[5+5];

            combine=conca(My_arr, Arr);

            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                if (i==0)
                    Console.Write("{0}",combine[i]);
                else if (i>=1)
                {
                    Console.Write(",");
                    Console.Write("{0}",combine[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        static char conca(char []My_arr,char []Arr)
        {
            int a=0,b=0;
            char []comb=new char[5+5];

            for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                if(i%2==0)
                {
                    for (int j=a;j<a+1;j++)
                    {
                        comb[i] = My_arr[j];

                    }a++;
                }
               else if (i%2!=0)
                {
                    for (int k=b;k<b+1;k++)
                    {
                        comb[i]=Arr[k];

                    }b++;
                }
            }
            return comb;
        }
    }
}
```

Hello this program is takes two array (char) and merge them like this (1,a,2,b,3, ....).But  I can't find where i mistaken and how to solve this problem.I tried every thing but can't get the solution. I have seen answers of different people related to this problem but cannot find my mistakes. Help is needed

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the conca method is incorrect, you should return an array of char.

```
    static char[] conca(char[] My_arr, char[] Arr)
    {
       // ...
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot now my program runs and it gives my desire output